# How to get notification on my server if any event is edited or deleted on user Google calender

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

After the successful authentication on Google, user get event information
Which is processed on our server.
But if any events edit or delete user is not able to getting update regarding this, user need again call calender api.
How we can get changing update regarding google calendar events on our server without again call of calendar api.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to receive a notification to your server whenever a calendar event changes.

If that's the case, consider using push notifications:

- First, set up a URL where notifications will be received.
- Second, call [Events: watch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/watch) to set up the notification channel.

Take a look at [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push) for a complete guide on this, and [Events: watch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/watch) for documentation on the method you'll have to call after setting up the webhook.

Comment: Is there any other way without using push notification?

Comment: @The_N If this were a Calendar add-on, you could use [EventUpdateTrigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/calendar-addons#eventupdatetrigger) for this. But since you mentioned add-ons, I guess that's not your situation? If it's not, then push notifications is the only option.

Comment: @The_N There's a typo in my previous comment, should be `But since you didn't mention add-ons`